# Trace a PNG image to an SVG Programmatically in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm looking for a .net library or open source project that traces a PNG image in to vector and can output an SVG image, I'm open to paying for a license. I've had a good look around and couldn't find anything that fits. Is there anything out there?

The PNG files I have are really simple black and white lines so it's nothing too complicated.

Comment: Check out "Potrace": http://potrace.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks I have been looking in to it but it seems kind of fragile calling it from the cmd line.

Comment: Found out there is a port for c# of Potrace so I'm trying that. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a port of Potrace for C# .net

http://www.drawing3d.de/Downloads.aspx

It's called Vectorization and it seems to work pretty well for my needs